# Shell Script to Remove specific character in specific Position

Tags: text-processing

Please assume the below data .
For easy understanding , I using 29th Column Position  below
I wanted to check if Position 29 starts with Alphabets or number  . If Alphabets for example in 1st line Letter 'U' needs to be removed for 2nd line 'D' needs
to be removed and 3rd line no action since its starts with Number

```
47720920010500002           U314178
37966744783100812           D123455
37966880762200334           356678
```

I tried the following

```
sed 's/^\(.\{212\}\)U/\&/' $file_name
```

... to replace the 212th Character 'U' with Space.

```
cut -c -211,213- $file_name
```

... to remove the Space from the 212th Position

If its constant U , this code should work.  Need some help with commands if any available to check for all the aplhabets from a-z

Comment: Confused by "if it starts". Do you mean that **1st** position has to be alphabetic to delete the 212th ?

Comment: Please add sample data that is reflective of your real data and the expected output, and, if possible, the `sed` code you have already tried to make it easier to understand your request and the output expected.

Comment: In the sample data, do `U` `D` `2` occur in 1st position or 212th?

Comment: Your example clearly doesn't have 212 characters on the line. Please [edit] your question and add i) an example that reproduces your data and ii) the output you want from that example. Do you want to delete the character? Print it? Change the original file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify, don't use comments because they are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. Your `cut` command doesn't remove characters, so it is hard to understand what you need. Please make sure to include the output you expect from the input example you give.

Comment: Sorry if my question was confusing, Updated the question again with details.

Comment: Please fix it again - right now your text says you want to work on the 29th character but your code is trying to work on the 212th character. Change your code to match your example. We don't care how many characters your real world data has, just the example you provide for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with your:

> ```
> sed 's/^\(.\{212\}\)U/\&/' $file_name
> ```

You did capture the first 212 characters by using `\(...\)`. All you had to do is refer to that with `\1` in the replacement. `&` would have replaced it with the whole matched text including the `U`. `\&` replaces with a literal `&`.

Also, if it's the 212<sup>th</sup> character you want to remove, it's 211 characters you want to match before that, not 212.

So:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{211\}\)U/\1/' < "$file_name"
```

Or:

```
sed -- 's/^\(.\{211\}\)U/\1/' "$file_name"
```

(also adding the missing quotes around `$file_name` and showing two different ways to guard against file names starting with `-` (the first one better as it also works for a file called `-` and avoids running `sed` if the file can't be opened))

Replace `U` with `[[:alpha:]]` to match any single letter (well, graphical symbols used in words of human language scripts that are not punctuation). Or `[[:upper:]]` for any uppercase letter, or `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]` for only the ASCII ones (and no, that's not the same as `[A-Z]` which also generally includes characters like `Æ`, `Ê` and even possibly multi-character collating elements such as `DZS` / `Dzs` in some locales).

Comment: Thank you so much and it worked :) sed 's/^\(.\{211\}\)[[:alpha:]]/\1/' $file_name

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can test and cut:

```
awk '! /^[[:alpha:]]/ { print; next; }
{ print substr ($0, 1, 211) substr ($0, 213); }'
```

Tested on shorter data (removing 4th position).

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk 'substr($0,29,1) ~ /[[:alpha:]]/{ $0=substr($0,1,28) substr($0,30) } 1' file
47720920010500002           314178
37966744783100812           123455
37966880762200334           356678
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -pe 's/ ^ .**28 <(<alpha>)> //;'
```

OR

```
raku -pe 's/ ^ .**28 <(<:L>)> //;'
```

Above detects if, after the first 28 characters, the 29th letter is either `<alpha>` (first example) or `<:L>` (Unicode letter, second example). The `<:L>` character class is short for `<:Letter>` and either can be used.

Technically, `<alpha>` matches alphabetic characters plus underscore (_). On the other hand, the `<:L>` character class uses the Unicode General Category name.

The regexes above employ Capture Markers, `<(`…`)>`, to drop recognized elements outside of the `<alpha>` / `<:L>` character that the OP desires omitted.

Sample Input:

```
47720920010500002           U314178
37966744783100812           D123455
37966880762200334           356678
```

Sample Output:

```
47720920010500002           314178
37966744783100812           123455
37966880762200334           356678
```

https://raku.org